# TeeChart exporting very small numbers as zeroes

Tags: teechart

I use TeeChart for .NET 2010 to chart sensor measurements. The chart itself works well and all points are displayed correctly. However, when attempting to export the chart data, very small numbers (e.g. 4.1245678E-10) will be exported as zero (0).

Is there something I am not setting right or is this a limitation of the export functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is produced because you need set the Series ValueFormat before exporting the Chart Data.  You can do something as code below:

```
bar1.ValueFormat = "#.#"+"x10" +"E+0";
```

To know more about the Standard Numeric Format Strings taking a look in the link below: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx